# Hibernate doesn't generate id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I have a Java spring project using hibernate to store its data into a postgresql database. Manually writing data into the database and reading it with hibernate works fine. However, saving newly created objects with hibernate to the database fails because hibernate tries to write null into the id column of the corresponding table (which is declared primary key).

Here the beginning of the POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="recipes")
public class Recipe implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3239162951065313443L; // generated by eclipse

@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Column(name="title")
private String title;

@Column(name="description")
private String description;

    // and so on ...
```

This is my method in the service class:

```
public void add(String title, String description, String content,
        int preparationEndurance, int totalEndurance, Date creation) {
    logger.debug("Adding new recipe");

    // Retrieve session from Hibernate
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    // Create a new Recipe
    Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
    recipe.setTitle(title);
    recipe.setDescription(description);
    recipe.setContent(content);
    recipe.setPreparationEndurance(preparationEndurance);
    recipe.setTotalEndurance(totalEndurance);
    recipe.setCreation(creation);

    // Save
    session.save(recipe);
}
```

This is the root cause of the exception:

```
Schwerwiegend: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path     [/webkochbuch] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with  root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: NULL-Wert in Spalte „id“ verletzt Not-Null- Constraint
Detail: Fehlgeschlagene Zeile enthält (null, n, b, v, 1, 7, 2013-12-10 16:33:49.478).
at      org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2161)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1890)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:560)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:363)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2989)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3501)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:393)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:227)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:207)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:191)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:764)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:756)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:752)
at org.cookbookgeeks.webkochbuch.service.RecipeService.add(RecipeService.java:92)
at org.cookbookgeeks.webkochbuch.service.RecipeService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d8f1ce7b.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
at org.cookbookgeeks.webkochbuch.service.RecipeService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$32728e81.add(<generated>)
at org.cookbookgeeks.webkochbuch.web.RecipeController.addRecipe(RecipeController.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you have auto-incremement on the table?

Comment: The id column is from the type "serial". I read that this is an integer with a constraint making it auto increment (in postgres at least).

Comment: Making it constraint won't make auto-incremement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Sequence in Postgres Database.

**Create Sequence**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence
  INCREMENT 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 100000;
```

Update your ID as

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE")
```

Now, when you persist it'll pick the next value from the `Sequence`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try that soon. One question: what is the reason behind 100000 as start and not, e.g. 0? (I'm relatively new to database systems and sql...)

Comment: The reason I have put 10000 in case you already have assigned some ids. You can set that to 0 as well.If this helps Thumb up and accept as an aswer.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. I did everything as you explained, but the same exception is thrown.

Comment: OK. Can you try strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE >

Comment: Yeah, I also just tried that and it works (I also granted the user USAGE rights on the sequence in the postgres database).

Answer (score 0):

Use Hibernate's Identity strategy. It will create the sequence for you. Try it, it works.